# How to display data from firebase inside the spinner for filtering method without having the same data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a filtering method in my application. So, I want to display all the city from the firebase database inside my spinner without display the same city. For your information, the city is in the EditText field.

My coding:-

```
private void loadFireBaseDataList(final String referenceKey)
{
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(referenceKey);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            final List<String> identity2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            identity2.add(0, "Location");

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 : snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    identity2.add(dataSnapshot2.child("adstuitioncity").getValue(String.class));
                }
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> nameAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FilterTuitionCentre.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, identity2);
            nameAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spLocation.setAdapter(nameAdapter2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

My database:-

[image]

My interface output:-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Set<String>` which contains no duplicates:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    Set<String> cities = new HashSet<String>();

    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        // ...
        cities.add(value)
    }

    List<String> identity2 = new ArrayList<String>(cities);
    identity2.add(0, "Location") 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FilterTuitionCentre.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, identity2);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Okay sir, then how to call the data from the firebase database?

Comment: Nothing else has changed, you just use `Set` instead of `List`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! It works! Sir can I have your email?

Comment: Sir, can you help me with this ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029316/the-tuition-packages-data-in-the-second-node-did-not-save-in-the-firebase-databa

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar with Firebase real-time database :(

Comment: Its okay sir, thanks. Can I have your email, I want to ask more about the toast msg indise my filtering...